# Never in my life have I been more curious to learn something than this course. Is this sentence correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, sentence, sentence-patterns, word-formation

I was wondering if the following sentence was grammatically correct or not.

**Never in my life have I been more curious to learn something than this course.**

Comment: You don’t learn a course—you learn a subject or a topic, or learn about something.

Comment: I believe it's grammatical, but it's very strange. It's certainly not how it would be written in a formal construction. It would be natural if *than this course* were dropped entirely. Or if that phrase were put at the start: *As for this course, never in my life have I been more curious to learn something.*

Comment: It doesn't make sense to me. I think it should be something like _...than I am to take this course_